# Book Identification: young adult sci-fi with a Christian slant/influence 90s/80s novel part of a series

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, space-colonization

Scifi novel published around 80s or 90s, part of a series.

- Interplanetary space opera with a young adult slant/approach.
- Earth colony, but Earth is not featured or mentioned.
- Main story centered around solar system with two suns, one main sun where all the "core" planets are located and where the main seat of government/alliance is based, and a smaller sun orbiting the main sun with smaller planets orbiting the smaller sun.
- Main conflict comes from the other planets rebelling/declaring civil war/declaring independence from the main planet/government.
- The protagonists are young (teens maybe); they are on vacation when war breaks out, protagonists know how to fly spaceships/planes but have to travel on foot to the planet's capital to escape & return to their father who is a captain/admiral/important government or space fleet/navy officer.
- Technology is highly discouraged or destroyed on the protagonists' planet during the revolt.
- Transportation mechanism is like a door appears out of thin air and on the opposite of the transporter door is a spaceship/warship.
- Ending part of the novel entails

  > the protagonists sneaking into the mayor's (presidential?) home in the capital city, the last place with technology/electricity and has anti-orbital bombardment shields turned on as the capital city is being attacked/bombarded by rebel forces. The protagonists are able to turn on an emergency beacon/send a message to their father and they are rescued via transporter.
- There are elements of religious/religion influences:

  > books are being burned on the protagonists' planet, but before they leave via the transporter door, one of the protagonists buries his/her Bible(?) or other important book near the presidential/mayor's house or yard that becomes main driver of the 2nd book in the series.

It's driving me crazy that I know all of these details but can't Google/search for this book.

Answer (score 4):

[Saga of the Six Worlds series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/70749-saga-of-the-six-worlds), by Cherith Baldry. Good books.

- Interplanetary travel, although I wouldn't have called it a space opera as most events happen planetside.
- Some vague allusions to the planet the system colonists came from (enough to identify as Earth), especially in the chronologically first book that tells the story of their rebellion.
- Binary system with two planets around Beta and four around Alpha.
- Initial conflict stems from rebellion from Earth, and results in total isolation from all out-system civilization; centuries later, the governing planet in-system is Center, and there's various rebellions fomented against them.
- A luddite movement arises on all six planets at the time of the rebellion, weakest on Center; this destroys enough knowledge that only Center can still manage spaceflight.

Etc.